# Form::Model eloquent binding

Tags: php, forms, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm having problems populating values of my inputs when I have eloquent queries using `with(`

Controller:

```
private $viewPath = "pages.person.";

public function edit($id)
{
    $person = Person::where('id', '=', $id)->with('Email', 'Phone', 'User', 'Client', 'JuridicPerson.TypeActivities')->firstOrFail();

    $this->setData('person', $person); // Set information to be used in the creation of `views` and `nest.views`.
    $this->setData('users', User::lists('name', 'id'), ['0' => 'Select…']); // Set information to be used in the creation of `views` and `nest.views`.

    return $this->view($this->viewPath.'edit'); // Register a new view.
}
```

My views are made in a way that I share the form between my `edit` and my `create`. So I have `create.blade.php`, `edit.blade.php` and both made a call to `form.blade.php` this I **can not** change.

My `edit.blade`

```
{{ Form::model($person, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'class' => 'defaultForm', 'route' => array('person.update', $person->id))) }}
    @include('pages.person.form')
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My `form.blade`

```
<!-- This input brings the correct value -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ Form::input('name', 'name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nome', 'maxlength' => 35, 'required', 'autofocus']) }}
    </div>
</div>
<!-- This input value is empty -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ Form::textarea('Client[observation]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Observations']) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**But** if I add this piece of code anywhere in my html, I get the correct value in `client`...

```
{{ $person->client }}
```

Not sure what should I do to fix my code, the data is correct, when I print the data (above code) the inputs output the correct value (but I can't have the the return printed on the screen for the user).

---

What I need is to print the correct value into the correct input.

Comment: In your `with()` function, try `client` instead of `Client` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: That's it! Thanks, I don't know why the code didn't show an error, but now it's working =) thanks. post as an answer so I can accept

Comment: There was no error. Your relations are stored in the `$relations` array, so `$relations[Client] != $relations[client]` and form model binding doesn't load the relation. Apparently you loaded `Client` but tried to call `client` (or the other way around).

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk that is correct, it was exactly what I was trying to do. Was an error of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `client` rather than `Client` when loading that relationship.

When you did `{{ $person->client }}` it had the side effect of loading that client relationship so it could be used.

When loading relationships, you should use the name of the function, exactly, that's responsible for setting up those relationships.